# Как в консоли на языке C# вычислить диапазон ip адресов по адресу и маске сети?

Tags: c#

Как в консоли на языке C# вычислить диапазон ip адресов по адресу и маске сети?
Число после символа '/' означает количество единиц в маске сети (от 0 до 32 включительно).

**Пример:**

Входные данные:
196.68.1.120/27

Выходные данные:
196.68.1.97 - 196.68.1.126

Comment: Из вопроса непонятна проблема. Если непонятно как это посчитать в принципе, то причем тут C# и консоль, нужно было так и написать? Если проблемы с кодом, то где, собственно, проблемный код?

Answer (score 0):

27 указывает, что 32-27=5 используются под адреса внутри сети.
Обнулим последние 5 бит маски. Получится (последние 8 бит) 11100000 - это 96.
11100001 первый адрес. 127 тоже использовать нельзя.

Comment: Можете реализовать алгоритм, пожалуйста, очень нужно

Comment: Здесь не одобряют, когда человек сам хоть плохой код, не пишет.

Comment: Напишите код, где запрашивается строка, вызывается функция и выводится результат. Саму функцию я напишу.